# PHP fsockopen()

Tags: php, fsockopen

a simple short question can i pass the host's ip in the fsockopen() function instead of its name?i need to set a connection between 2 servers and right now i have to work on the same computerm,I've never used fsockopen before so a simple example is appreciated
Thanks in advance =)

Comment: It's possible. See the manual for examples: http://php.net/fsockopen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say, instead of using `fsockopen()` to do HTTP between the two servers, it would be easier  to use [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) then, because it already has anything you would need.

Technically, if you use `fsockopen()` to do HTTP communication, you are going to develop another HTTP client. As curl is an HTTP client, I can't see the need to reinvent the wheel^^

**EDIT**:

So you really **must** use `fsockopen()`?

Ok. Here's a link to Simon Willisons PHP [HTTP client](http://scripts.incutio.com/httpclient/). Maybe it's old and outdated, and covers only a very small subset of an HTTP client functionality, but it comes with source and should help you getting on track on how to use `fsockopen` to do an HTTP request.

Comment: curl same as servlet right?!
i thinks ts not possible i should use fsockopen which btw is not working! i dunno is it google or me but i cant find where to start!:(

Comment: @user635614: just click on the `curl` link in the first paragraph of my answer. This should get you started. And no, curl is no java servlet, it's an PHP extension.

Comment: i did! but i told you we must use fsockopen() ! :( it's a course project!

Answer (score 1):

for e.g.

```
fsockopen(gethostbyaddr("127.0.0.1"), ...
```

Comment: Thanks,
so each 'server' has to be put on a different port to be able to communicate between them?

Comment: what exactly are you going to do with this connection? if they going to communicate, i think soap is a much better approach http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Comment: i must get data from clients send it to the server using Ajax and send it to the other server upon request...i've never used fsockopen() so i have no idea where to start!it must be done using it...

Comment: @user635614: what protocol is going to be used?

Comment: TCP,did i answer ur question?

Comment: @user635614: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I wanted to know which _communication_ protocol (HTTP, SSL, FTP, SMTP, POP3, IMAP, etc.) is going to be used (not the _transport_ protocol, which will be TCP as you wrote).

Answer (score 0):

using fsockopen function does't secure. This function often disabled by hosting providers for security reasons, also hosting providers have protect from foreign connections to other machines by firewall.

If you want to get something by one server from another using php, just use CURL. You need installed curl php extension to use it.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://yourserver.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$r = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Also if you use Zend Framework, you can set eyes on Zend_Http_Adapter_Curl classes